# A pregnant woman of a boy kohen baby going into cemetery

Tags: kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, pregnancy-birth, cemetery-grave

The gemara in chullin 71 writes that a tahor baluah cannot become tamei.  Meaning something inside someone cannot become tamei from the outside. So it seems from this gemara that a woman who married a kohen and is pregnant would have no issue going into a cemetery or coming in contact with a dead body,since tahor baluah.

So why have I seen people who know they are having a boy (through ultrasound or something) be stringent not to come into contact with tumah?

Comment: [Here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1246130/jewish/Pregnant-Women-in-Cemeteries.htm) they say that there is a custom to do this, despite strong halakhic grounds for leniency

Comment: R H Schachter writes about this at length. See a summary https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/sonograms-and-kohanims-wives-part-two-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

Comment: Can you summarize what Rav Jachter writes?

Comment: In a resp. re. the general question of a pregnant woman coming in contact with tum’ah, R. Pinchas Zabihi has an extensive note re. specifically where through ultrasound the woman knows she will have a male ([Ateret Paz vol. 1 YD §3 note 1](http://www.bsd-paz.org/Texts/AteretPaz_v2_Yore_Dayah/comments/html/E7ECF75FE05FEBF8EA5FE15FE9E5F8E45FE3F2E45FF1E9EEEF5FE25FE4F2F8E45FE05FE7ECF75FE0.htm)). He, and other contemporary poskim are lenient. On a different note, some have the custom not to enter cemeteries for superstitious reasons.

Comment: (cf. Shevet Mussar [ch. 24](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevet_Musar.24?vhe=Shevet_Musar,_Fiyorda,_1761&lang=bi) - “גם תהיה נזהרת בפרט בימי עיבורה שלא תכנס במקומות של טומאה... לפי שהולד נוצר בפי ראות עיניה”). - didn’t fit in previous comment. (PS, don’t mean to scoff at the practice; by “superstitious” I merely meant *meta-halachic*.

Answer (score 2):

The [Sifte Kohen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbatai_HaKohen) ([YD beg. §371](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.371.1.1?with=all&lang=bi)) quotes the [Rokeach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) saying that the wife of a Kohen may enter under the same “roof” as a corpse since there is a double-doubt: the newborn may be a stillborn and, even if it is not, it may be a female. The question was posed to [Radbaz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) ([§200](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_1.200?lang=bi)): Why is such reasoning necessary, this is a case of *tumah balu’ah*? Radbaz therefore suggests that Rokeach was concerned with a situation where the woman is close to giving birth and we are suspect that the newborn might begin to exit the body whereby it is considered born and no longer *balu’ah* and so necessitated his “double-doubt” reasoning (cf. Chazon Ovadiah - Avelut vol. 2 pp. 63-68 quoting numerous authorities who [implicitly] agree that the fact of *tumah balu’ah* is alone sufficient reason to be unconcerned with a fetus contracting *tum’ah*, except that the double-doubt is necessary for a more extenuating circumstance).

As such, I believe the reason for a pregnant wife of a Kohen to be stringent and not enter a cemetery probably stems from esoteric reasons (cf. my comment to the question), unless the case in question is concerning a woman who has a chance of giving birth while visiting in the cemetery.